# Quality of USB hubs?

Tags: usb, camera

What are the characteristics that specify the quality of a USB hub? I want to connect multiple devices (dslr cameras) to a desktop computer (more than 20), so i wonder which is the most reliable USB hub that i can use.

Comment: You will want a powered usb hub that supplys the greatest amount of Amps depending if we are talking about USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 devices.

Comment: More than 20, simultaneously? You need to worry less about your hubs than about your system's USB controllers; that's a fairly high number of simultaneously connected USB devices, and if they're all talking at once, odds are none of them will be able to do so particularly quickly.

Comment: @Ramhound Still conflating USB transfer rates and current source requirements, I see. Honestly, I despair of you.

Comment: @AaronMiller - I am not confusing anything. Your welcome to correct me if you want, if you feel my statement, isn't a valid suggestion.  **If you have completely lost hope, then I feel sorry for you, because I am very eager to learn provided the information I am told is actually accurate.**

Comment: Possible Dupe: [What makes a good and reliable USB Hub?](http://superuser.com/questions/260646/what-makes-a-good-and-reliable-usb-hub), also see [How many devices can be plugged into a USB hub, and how is power distributed amongst them?](http://superuser.com/questions/330556/how-many-devices-can-be-plugged-into-a-usb-hub-and-how-is-power-distributed-amo?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Go for a USB hub which have a separate power input to it. there are many USB hubs which have a single USB cable to connect to PC, but these hubs uses the power output of the PC USB port and is shared with all the ports available on the USB hub. this will result in malfunction and connectivity issues.

Comment: @20317 : this product will be needed for you [MondoHub](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/eecf/)