# Why does my generic USB hub not allow my PC to find a second plugged-in flash drive?

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, usb-hub

On my Dell Model i3531-1200BK (running Windows 8.1)
I am using a 4 slot (no name) generic USB hub that works fine with one flash drive. But when a second flash drive is inserted, the laptop starts searching for the second flash drive but never finds it, and nether drive will work.

I took the hub back to the store where it was purchased.  They tried it on their Windows 8.1 laptop, and it worked fine.

I checked for driver updates, and it stated that the hub driver was up to date. I am running the laptop at high performance, I've performed a deep power cycle and fsc scan, and I have installed all Microsoft updates.

In "Power Management" I have un-checked the box "allow this computer to power off this device to save power".

The only thing connected to the other USB port on the laptop is a mouse. I have tried both ports on the laptop.

How can I get my hub to support two flash drives simultaneously?

Comment: Sounds like a power problem; without device specifics; will be hard to diagnose

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ramhound in that it sounds like a lack of USB power being supplied by your notebook.

Get and try a [self-powered USB hub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub#Power) that has its own power supply.

Perhaps check out this related SU question: [What makes a good and reliable USB Hub?](https://superuser.com/questions/260646/what-makes-a-good-and-reliable-usb-hub)

Comment: I want to thank you guys for your comments. I tried a powered usb hub and the laptop now works fine. Hard to believe this laptop does not have enough usb power to find 2 usb drives on a non-powered hub